# Exit YoutubePlayer full-screen on YouTube API V3 programatically

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, android-fullscreen

The question basically explains itself.

I have tried player.setFullscreen(false);

That does nothing but call the OnFullscreen method in OnFullscreenListener

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#setFullscreen(boolean)

I think they did not implement a way for you to close it without user interaction otherwise it would've been obvious. (Just making sure)

If you wonder why I need it, its because I want to exit fullscreen player when user presses the back button. Another issue is that I disabled landscape so it will not automatically switch to normal view when you return to portrait.

Maybe I could programatically make it so it seems like I switch to landscape but in reality I dont, just to fool the player?

Any solutions or ideas appreciated. Thanks.

---

Here is some parts of my activity that are relevant:

```
Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    if (groupPosition == 2) {
        String videoId = episodeList.get(childPosition).getYoutubeId();
        if (this.currentVideoId == null) {
            currentVideoId = videoId;
            currentFragment = YoutubeVideoFragment.newInstance(videoId);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtube_video_area, currentFragment).commit();
            showVideoFragment();
        }
        else if (!this.currentVideoId.equals(videoId)) {
            cleanupRetainInstanceFragment();
            currentFragment = YoutubeVideoFragment.newInstance(videoId);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtube_video_area, currentFragment).commit();
        }
        else
            toggleVideoFragment();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}


public void cleanupRetainInstanceFragment() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this.currentFragment).commit();
    youtubePlayer.release();
    youtubePlayer = null;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (videoFullscreen) {
        youtubePlayer.pause();
        youtubePlayer.setFullscreen(false);
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onVideoFragmentAttachSuccess(YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {       
    //here I get the youtubePlayer instance with a listener interface set up in my fragment. It works correctly.
    this.youtubePlayer = youTubePlayer;

}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your whole activity? And I'd like to see where do you use `player.setFullscreen(false)`?

Comment: I just made an edit to the question. The part you might be interested in is the onBackPressed() override.

Comment: @rom4ek I just checked Youtube app itself to see if they had it and apparently not. They exit from the activity completely instead of exiting fullscreen when back button is pressed.

Comment: @rom4ek I solved it. I ran a check in all my booleans and found that videoFullscreen was false all the time. Such a stupid mistake.